# Open front face camera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am trying to open front facing camera but its opening default back camera.Please Suggest me how to achieve this?

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
StorageFile photo =await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

if (photo == null)
{
    // User cancelled photo capture
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CameraCaptureUI, you can try to use the MediaCapture class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642092.aspx

You can query for the available cameras by using DeviceInformation class, for example:

```
  DeviceInformation device = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
      .FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation != null && d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
```

and if a device is returned, set it's id in the MediaCaptureInitializationSettings class:

```
MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
settings.VideoDeviceId = device.Id;

MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
```